# Gmail on iPad not working ..error message

Tags: gmail, settings, error

I'm seeing this problem all over the web and I'm asking the same thing. I am not very computer savvy and would appreciate an answer that is easy to understand.

When I try to access my Gmail account on my iPad by clicking on the mail icon that came with the device (meaning: I'm not using my browser to access my mail and not using any downloaded apps) I get this message:

The mail server "imap.gmail.com" is not responding. Verify that you have entered the correct account info in Mail settings.

And I have. And do. Everything is correct. 
This started to be a problem before the new ios6 update.  And I can access my gmail account on my iPhone just fine.  This problem is just on my iPad 2.

Also. I do have another gmail account set up on my iPad and that email works fine. They both have been on my iPad for ever and both been fine until a few weeks ago. Just one account is messed up!  Why? And why hasn't this been fixed?

Comment: I agree. Delete the account and set it up a second time. I had the exact thing happen with my iPad, and I deleted the account, set it up again, and it worked like new.

Comment: An alternate solution would be to add a second gmail account to see if the problem is the iPad or the network connection to gmail or the account. Also - the steps to get gmail working very depending on whether you have application specific passwords set up.

Answer (score 1):

Try a couple things:

1. Delete the problem gmail account from your iPad, and then set it up again.  See if email works.
2. If #1 doesn't work, then it could be possible you have too many devices accessing that email account at the same time (ie., iMac/notebooks/etc with the Mail app left open).  Try closing the mail app on your other devices and see if that works.  I believe gmail has a limit of 10 devices that can access the same email account at a given time.  A mail app left open counts as one.
3. Lastly, make sure you've inputted the correct password.  You might want to change your password in gmail.com and then re-enter it in your iPad.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Has anyone talked with the Apple geniuses? What did they say was the fix? I would be cautious about deleting and reinstalling the gmail account for fear of losing emails.

Comment: @Bill The chance that an iPad has the only copy of a message is slim to none - and in practice, the only thing you might lose is a draft message you are working on that isn't stored online or a message that you "sent" but is still queued for sending.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem for a while. It went away about the time I applied an iOS update, so I'm wondering if it might have been a bug that Apple squashed? If you're still on iOS6, consider updating.

Answer (score -1):

Restart your iphone or mac and try it again. Magic ;)